# Proving that a limit goes to $0$ for every $\epsilon > 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm studying for an exam. This is a problem I cannot solve, and I would appreciate any help with.

Let $\{X_{n}\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables and suppose $\mathbb{E}[X_{1}] = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}|X_{1}|^{2} < \infty$. Prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_{n}}{n^{1/2 + \epsilon}} = 0$$

almost surely.

---

I think I need to show

$$P(\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_{n}(\omega)}{n^{1/2 + \epsilon}} = 0\}) = 1. $$

I tried to use Kolmogorov's $0$-$1$ Law and many other convergence theorems with no luck. I would really appreciate anyone's help to help me prepare for my exam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use Borel-Cantelli for this one... (click for spoilers)

> It suffices to show that for all $\delta>0$, it holds with probability $1$ that there are only finitely many $n$ such that $|X_n|>\delta n^{\tfrac12+\epsilon}$.

Okay, if that hint wasn't enough...

> The expected number of $n$ such that $|X_n|>\delta n^{\tfrac12+\epsilon}$ equals the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(|X_1|^2>\delta^2 n^{1+2\epsilon})$$

Last step...

> By Markov's inequality, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(|X_1|^2>\delta^2 n^{1+2\epsilon})\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb E|X_1|^2}{\delta^2n^{1+2\epsilon}},$$ which converges to a finite number. Since the expectation is finite, that means that with probability $1$ there are only finitely many $n$ such that $|X_n|>\delta n^{\tfrac12+\epsilon}$.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Borel-Cantelli lemma. I think you are using the second Borel Cantelli Lemma, right? My statement says that if $E_{n}$ are independent and the sum of probabilities of the $E_{n}$ diverges to infinity, then the probability that infinitely many of them occur is $1$. Could you please clarify a little bit on how to get from this statement to "it suffices to show that for all $\delta > 0$, it holds with probability $1, \ldots$"? Thanks!!

Comment: No, it is the first Borel-Cantelli lemma, and it does not require independence. It says that if the sum of the probabilities is finite, then the probability that infinitely many occur is $0$.

Comment: Why do we introduce $\delta$? Can't we define $E_{n} = \{|X_{n}| > n^{1/2 + \epsilon}\}$?

Comment: Since the sum is finite (in the last spoiler), it means that the probability of infinitely $|X_n|$ being "too big" is zero. Or in other words, the probability of only finitely many of the $|X_n|$ being too "big" is $1$. Thus with probability $1$, we have that $\limsup_n |X_n|/{n^{\tfrac12+\epsilon}}<\delta$. Finally, choose a sequence of $\delta$ tending to $0$ to get that limit. We need $\delta$ to do this since if we leave it out, all you showed is that the limit is somewhere between $-1$ and $1$ (or might not exist, really the limsup/liminf are in that interval).

Comment: Thanks. How did you see the answer so quickly?

Comment: Using Borel-Cantelli like this is bread and butter for a probabilist... after dozens of times, you start to pick up on it pretty quickly. Use Borel-Cantelli like this when you want to prove an a.s. event and you know some moment bound.